# Trying to understand why these two functions are not equivalent

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

I'm working on some bit shifting in javascript and trying to understand why these two bit shifting functions aren't equivalent. The purpose is to count the number of set bits in a byte.

```
// correct output
let x = 13;
for (var c = 0; x; x >>= 1) {
  c += x & 1;
}
// outputs: c === 3
```

And:

```
//incorrect output
let y = 13;
var b = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  y >>= 1;
  b += y & 1;
}
// outputs: b === 2
```

Comment: this question is nonsensical

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you said why you thought they *should* be equivalent?

Comment: @self sorry, why is it nonsensical?

Comment: @JK because they iterate the same number of times and in the non-working version the shifting is done in the loop rather that the 'for' declaration. They should be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incorrect version drops the right-most bit in the initial y in `y >>= 1` *before* adding the bit to b (so it happens to give correct result when y is 12).

Comment: So just swap the order of the two statements in the second loop.

Comment: Thanks guys! Ok I see what the issue was now.